# Cronbach's Alpha on true and false data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binary-data, reliability, psychometrics, cronbachs-alpha

I have a 10 item knowledge scale (true/false). Can I do Cronbach alpha test?

Answer (score 5):

From wikipedia, [Kuder–Richardson Formula 20](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuder%E2%80%93Richardson_Formula_20):

> "In statistics, the Kuder–Richardson Formula 20 (KR-20) first published in 1937 is a measure of internal consistency reliability for measures with dichotomous choices. It is analogous to Cronbach's α, except Cronbach's α is also used for non-dichotomous (continuous) measures."